# Having trouble evaluating this integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int\limits_6^{16}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3+7x^2+8x-16}}\right)\,\mathrm dx=\frac{\pi }{k}$$

**Note:** $k$ is a constant.

Comment: Definitely +1..

Comment: We have $x^3+7x^2+8x-16=(x-1)(x+4)^2$. Do then the substitution $u=\sqrt{x-1}$.

Comment: If you follow the steps in my answer, you'll get $k=6\sqrt5$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$x^3+7x^2+8x-16=(x-1)(x+4)^2\implies \sqrt{x^3+7x^2+8x-16}=\sqrt{x-1}(x+4)$$

Denote the indefinite integral as $I$.

$$I=\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{(x+4)\sqrt{x-1}}$$

Make the substitution $u^2=x-1$ and $2u\,\mathrm du=\mathrm dx$ to get,

$$I=2\int\frac{\mathrm du}{u^2+5}$$

This is an elementary integral which can be evaluated easily. Put the limits and get the value of $k$

Comment: Thanks for the unnecessary downvote. I appreciate it. -_-

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Since $x^3+7x^2+8x-16=(x-1)(x+4)^2$, I suggest you to do the substitution $u=\sqrt{x-1}$. In the end, you will find that a primitive function is given by
$$
\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\arctan(\sqrt{x-1}/\sqrt{5}).
$$
The value of $k$? Well, I leave that fun to you!